# Android Application Deployment on LG P500 Device

Tags: android

I am developing the Web application in Android 2.2 and i want to deploy it on the LG P500 device. I am using Windows XP as an operating system. But i am facing the problem of installing the drivers on my system, it gives the error "Hardware not found the desired USB drivers". So give me any suggestion on this. 
      Also told me that it is possible on windows system or it required Linux System?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: have you installed LG PC Suite and the like? (in Linux, i plugged usb cable in and the phone showed up as available when manually choosing the device.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [similar question about this on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/218623/lg-p500-drivers-windows-7-x64), and the answer appeared to be to download and install the [LG Mobile Support Tool](http://www.lg.com/in/support/mc-support/mobile-phone-support.jsp), then use it to install the drivers.

As for the second part of your question: Yes, you can develop on Windows. There are [versions of the SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) for Windows, Mac and Linux. Most of the tutorials assume you are using Eclipse to develop, which is also cross-platform (as is Netbeans, another popular choice).

If you're looking to *build the Android source*, however, [Windows is not currently supported](http://source.android.com/source/download.html).